# Method to compare Python dictionaries fails with certain value types?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I can't figure this out.  I have two dictionaries which are identical.  I use a standard method to determine the differences, of which there should be none.  But certain value types are always returned as differences, even when they are not.  For example, if a value is a `pymongo.bson.ObjectId`, the method fails to evaluate it as the same.

```
d1 = {'Name':'foo','ref1':ObjectId('502e232ca7919d27990001e4')}

d2 = {'Name':'foo','ref1':ObjectId('502e232ca7919d27990001e4')}

d1 == d2
```

returns:

```
True
```

But:

```
set((k,d1[k]) for k in set(d1) & set(d2) if d1[k] != d2[k])
```

returns:

```
set([('ref1',Objectid('502e232ca7919d27990001e4'))])
```

So I've figured out that this is weird, no?

```
d1['ref1'] == d2['ref1']  # True

d1['ref1'] != d2['ref1']  # False
```

What the?????!?!??!!?

Comment: Are your two `ObjectId` values references to the same object, or are they different objects? Does the `ObjectId` class implement `__eq__` appropriately? I've tried to reproduce with a dummy `ObjectId` but I get the expected results (an empty set).

Comment: This is a great question, since according to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), "Mappings (dictionaries) compare equal if and only if their sorted (key, value) lists compare equal." So `d1 == d2` should imply `d1[k] == d2[k]`.

Comment: It's possible that `ObjectId` is a buggy class, where `hash(o)` is based on, e.g., `o.value`, but `o1==o2` is not. But if neither equality nor hashing are based on value, this is perfectly reasonable behavior.

Comment: @Blckknght same objects.  `__eq__` checks out, but `id` does not

Comment: @unutbu the post you deleted (?) earlier gave me the clue to try the `id` test.  I'm not sure what to make of the results though

Comment: @MFB: I was mistaken to bring up `id`. `id(obj1) == id(obj2)` implies `ob1 is obj2`, but it does not imply `obj1 == obj2`. It is a red herring. I deleted my answer because I could not explain how `d1 == d2` given that `d1['ref'] != d2['ref']`.

Comment: @unutbu ah ok.  Well the `id` is the only way I can get `False` outside of the comparison function.  So confused!

Comment: The only thing I can think of at this point is that you had a typo somewhere in your set comprehension which resulted in the stray value turning up. Its output seems to be entered wrong (it has a colon in it, which isn't valid in a tuple). Can you verify that you've typed both of those bits in the question correctly?

Comment: @Blckknght my bad, sorry.  Typo was only in the question though, not in my original code.

Comment: Thanks everyone and sorry for all the red herrings.. Its a bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectId('502e232ca7919d27990001e4')` creates a new object and by default `!=` compares references. Try for example:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

print Obj(1234) == Obj(1234) # False
```

This will evaluate to false, because they are difference instances, even if they hold the same value. To make this work, the class must implement the **eq** method:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value

print Obj(1234) == Obj(1234) # True
```

To fix this, you can "monkey-patch" the class:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

print Obj(1234) == Obj(1234) # False

Obj.__eq__ = lambda a, b: a.value == b.value

print Obj(1234) == Obj(1234) # True
```

Or compare them by their values directly.

```
print Obj(1234).value == Obj(1234).value
```

Compare the values when possible because monkey-patching may break seemingly unrelated code.

Comment: In this case, you should definitely add a `__hash__` method gauaranteed to return the same value for equal objects, such as `def __hash__(self): return hash(self.value)` in order to prevent the behaviour in the question from happening.

Comment: Thanks, you got me into test mode which helped me find the bug